# Is SFDC username considered case sensitive when used as SAML identifier?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, username

In our company we have some customers that login into our Experience Cloud portal using SAML in IDP-initiated mode. In SFDC federation setup, the Name IDentifier found in the SAML assertion will be considered as a Salesforce username, and we know that Salesforce usernames are case insensitive.

But currently we're facing a strange issue: when customer usernames have mixed upper and lower case letters, or all letters are in uppercase, SAML login doesn't work.

For example, Jane Doe is an employee of Acme Inc. and her username in her company network (we don't care if it's the UPN or SAM account name) is `Jane.Doe@acme.com`.
In SAML assertion we found `Jane.Doe@acme.com` as Name ID, while in Salesforce her username is `jane.doe@acme.com`. We're expecting that everything matches by case insensitivity rule, but Jane sees the error page and we find in the SAML Validator page the "user mismatch" error.
Instead, when Jane's network username is `jane.doe@acme.com` or it's added to SAML assertion in lowercase, it matches with Salesforce username and everything works.

Anyone knows why we're experiencing this behavior, and what we can do to fix this without requesting our customers to submit their usernames in lowercase form?

Also, if possible I prefer not to write a provisioning handler Apex class, only to match users using SOQL queries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not use User.FederationId (and use a before save flow to coerce a lowercase username into User.FederationId)?

Comment: _we know that Salesforce usernames are case insensitive_: this is true in many but not all scenarios. SAML is one scenario where this isn't true, the comparison is case-sensitive because the spec requires it to be so for NameID. Possible workaround: use [Federation ID + case-insensitive config option](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_auth_federation_id_case_sensitivity.htm&type=5&release=226)

Comment: @cropredy This could be a good tip, thanks!

Comment: @identigral Uh, unfortunately I'm not very expert about SAML protocol and I didn't know about Name ID case sensitivity. Thank you for your contribute.